# How to create PKCS7 Signatur with Python

Tags: python, cryptography, pkcs#7

I've want to create a PKCS7 Signature in the following format with Python:

‑‑‑‑‑BEGIN PKCS7‑‑‑‑‑
XXXX
‑‑‑‑‑END PKCS7‑‑‑‑‑

I've got the following Code:

```
with open(privKeyPath, "rb") as f:
        privKey = serialization.load_pem_private_key(f.read(), None)

    with open(pubCertPath, "rb") as f:
        pubCert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(f.read())

    options = [pkcs7.PKCS7Options.DetachedSignature]
    dataSigned = pkcs7.PKCS7SignatureBuilder().set_data(rawrequest.encode()).add_signer(pubCert, privKey, hashes.SHA256()).sign(serialization.Encoding.SMIME, options)
    
    base64_string = base64.b64encode(dataSigned).decode("ascii")

    pkcs7sig = "-----BEGIN PKCS7-----\n"
    pkcs7sig += base64_string
    pkcs7sig += "\n"
    pkcs7sig += "-----END PKCS7-----"

    return pkcs7sig
```

The signature ist not valid when I try to check it with OpenSSL. Any ideas on how to get the correct output?

Tried different encoding types and options to get the correct output file.

Comment: Try `serialization.Encoding.PEM` (instead of `serialization.Encoding.SMIME`) and output/return  `dataSigned.decode()`.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that worked. I thought I had already tried this option, but apparently I didn't.